# Can't find the source of TypeError when creating a matrix whose size depends upon the maximum value in a dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas

I want to create a square matrix of zeros whose size is the maximum of the positive entries in a particular column of a dataframe. The relevant lines are as follows, where numpy was imported as np and where df is my dataframe having one of its columns named 'labels':

```
n=df['label'].max()
print(n)
print(type(n))
M=np.zeros((n,n))
```

The print lines indicate n is computed correctly and of type 'numpy.int64'.

The error message arises when I attempt to define M and reads:

```
TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

I tried to replace

```
M=np.zeros((n,n)) with

M=np.zeros(int(n),int(n))
```

but that resulted in

```
valueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer.
```

Python 3.7 on Mac 10.15.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The errors you're receiving mean the following:

1. `TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer` This indicates that your `n` value is a float. However when creating an array via `np.zeros` they require an integer (following the logic that if your float is a true decimal such as `5.1`, you can not create an array with length/shape of `5.1`.
2. As per the above, you took the correct step of converting `n` to an integer. However, this error `ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer.` indicates that `n` is not actually a number- it is `NaN`, which inherits from numpy's float type. You can replicate this error with `int(np.nan)`. This means that `df["label"].max()` is returning `NaN` which should only happen if that column is entirely made of of `NaN` for some reason, so I would check your data.